# JSON-RPC 2 client for PHP able to call methods in nested classes

Tags: php, json-rpc

I have JSON-RPC2 server which provides interface to some services

```
$server = new Server;
$server->service1 = new Service1($this);
$server->service2 = new Service2($this);
```

I am wondering, if there is any (preferably PHP) client, which is able to call the methods of these services, as I need it for debug purposes.

I tested one client, which is able to call methods directly:

```
$client = new jsonRPCClient('http://localhost/jsonrpcphp/server.php');

// This works
$response = $client->giveMeSomeData('name');

// This doesn't
$response = $client->service1->giveMeSomeData('name');
```

My original client is CoffeScript application, which calls the methods in this way:

```
@get("api").call "service1.giveMeSomeData", "name", (result) =>
```

Is there any JSON-RPC2 client for PHP which I could use in the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON-RPC is a very simple protocol. The namespace of an endpoint is *FLAT*. There aren't classes exposed (let alone multiple classes) from a single endpoint.

When the CoffeeScript client is calling `service1.giveMeSomeData`, it's literally asking the PHP web-service to execute an endpoint method with the name `service1.giveMeSomeData`. If your web-service then routes that to the `giveMeSomeData` method in an instance of some class currently assigned to the instance `Service1`, well that's up to it! (the PHP service side). This is *NOT* a feature of JSON-RPC, it's something made up by the end-point router you're using.

The equivalent call on the PHP client side *might* be something like `$client->call('Service1.giveMeSomeData', array('name'))`
It depends on the JSON-RPC library you use. Some PHP client libraries construct an instance of an ad-hoc class, which implements the PHP `__call` method, such that any un-recognised method names are re-directed as calls to the generic RPC call method in that class.

To be clear, there are *not* multiple namespaces being served from the JSON-RPC endpoint, just a single *flat* namespace which *can* include methods with `.` (dot) characters in their names. How your web-service endpoint routes those calls to PHP functions/methods is completely up to you/it.

PS. You'll get much better help if you explain what client & server libraries you're using in PHP for JSON-RPC (there are *many*, of varying quality and completeness).